# Java setText() Error

Tags: java, swing

I am not understanding why I am getting a runtime error when I try to .setText() to a JTextArea Object in my program. In my main GUI class I have set up a event that creates a pop up JFrame object, this JFrame has a button in it which is set up too do a JTextArea.setText(); to a JTextArea in my main GUI class called MainOut.

```
public class GUI extends JFrame implements ActionListener {



JTextArea MainOut       =       new JTextArea(20,50);


public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {


        if (e.getSource() == ExitVar){
            System.exit(0);
        }

        else if (e.getSource() == ServerLoginVar) { //This is my event that creates a 
                                                            //new JFrame popup
            new ServerLoginGUI(this);   
        } 

//-------------------------------------------------------------------
public class ServerLoginGUI extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    JTextField ServerIP             = new JTextField(15);
    JPasswordField ServerPassword       = new JPasswordField(15);
    JPanel ServerLoginPanel         = new JPanel();
    JButton LoginButton         = new JButton("Login");
    JTextArea Area;
    JLabel ServerIPLabel            = new JLabel("Server Address:");
    JLabel ServerPasswordLabel      = new JLabel("Password      :");
    GUI GUi;
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        if (e.getSource() == LoginButton){
            if (ServerIP.getText().isEmpty() ||  ServerPassword.getText().isEmpty()){
                } //do nothing

            else {
                new ServerAccess(this);

// this is the .setText() that will generate a error

                GUi.SiteNameField.setText("Test from the ServerLogin event!");

                dispose();}
                    }
        }

}
```

Comment: are you sure that you are getting runtime errors? it seems you have more compile-time errors, huh?

Comment: What is the exception that is thrown ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

okay here is you problem. You have created the object of `GUI` in the `ServerLoginGUI` class. But you are not initializing your  `GUi` object with the reference of calling class. Here is what you need to do to fix this. To your `ServerLoginGUI` class add the following constructor:

```
public ServerLoginGUI(GUI gui)
{
  this.GUi = gui;
}
```

Now your code should work fine and not give a run time error. Which I am assuming is a nullpointer error though you have not specified.

PS: Please get the Java conventions right. Variables start with letter in lower case. :)

Comment: Humm your are 100% correct. I made the changes and now its working fine. I always thought that if the code is read left to right that you pass in your object and state that your passed in object = your locate reference variable.such as:                                                                           public getter(obj b){

Comment: Humm your are 100% correct. I made the changes and now its working fine. I always thought that if the code is read left to right that you pass in your object and state that your passed in object = your locate reference variable. My logic on this one is backwards to me this seems like your assigning the bitmap of the local object to class object? Well I guess I must be wrong so thank you.

Comment: great! Please accept the answer if it has worked for you! Thanks!